# How do you actually run scalajs code in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, scala.js

I'm developing a backend chat server. It's currently written in messy callback javascript so I'm considering porting it to scalajs.

I've been looking through the beginner's guides, but I can't find how to actually compile the project to a single javascript file that I can run with node (e.g. `node ./target/scala_2.11/my-project.js`).

How do you compile a single file that you can run directly as a node program, and not in the browser?

My code couldn't be simpler:

```
package example

import scala.scalajs.js
import js.Dynamic.{ global => g }

object ScalaJSExample extends js.JSApp {
  def main(): Unit = {
    g.console.log("*** Did something ***")
    println("Trying to print something...")
  }
}
```

`sbt run` correctly prints:

```
*** Did something ***
Trying to print something...
```

But when I run `sbt fullOptJS` and then `node ./target/scala-2.11/example-opt.js` nothing is printed to the console.

Comment: Why don't you just type `run` in sbt?

Comment: How do you deploy that?

Comment: You don't :) But to be fair, sbt on its own doesn't deploy as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `example-opt.js` does not contain the one line of JavaScript used to actually *launch* the code. It only defines `example.ScalaJSExample().main()` as a function, but it doesn't *call* it.

An easy way to make it call that function automatically is to instruct sbt to add the call at the end of the `.js` file with this sbt setting:

```
scalaJSOutputWrapper := ("", "example.ScalaJSExample().main();")
```

This will allow you to just invoke

```
node ./target/scala-2.11/example-opt.js
```

Comment: Thanks, I nearly thought I'd have to write a wrapper manually.

Comment: @sjrd in my POC that makes `run` launch the code twice. Any way to avoid that?