# Scala.js: How to access self in a Webworker

Tags: scala.js

So I have a webworker:

```
package pWorker    
import scala.scalajs.js._
import org.scalajs.dom._

object WorkScript extends scala.scalajs.js.JSApp
{
  def main(): Unit =  
  {
    val x = 4
    val y = 8
    val z = x + y
    println("Worker x + y =" -- z.toString)      
  }
}
```

When launched from the primary JavaScript thread the worker prints to the console as desired. But I can't find a way to call the equivalents of:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {}
self.postMessage(e.data);
```

that I would call from a straight Javascript file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As always in Scala.js, if you do not find existing types for a JavaScript API, you have the option to go with dynamic types or to write your own.

### Dynamic types

```scala
val self = js.Dynamic.global
self.addEventListener("message", { (e: dom.MessageEvent) =>
  ...
}
self.postMessage(someData)
```

### Static types

```scala
@js.native
object WorkerGlobal extends js.GlobalScope {
  def addEventListener(`type`: String, f: js.Function): Unit = js.native
  def postMessage(data: js.Any): Unit = js.native
}

WorkerGlobal.addEventListener("message", { (e: dom.MessageEvent) =>
  ...
}
WorkerGlobal.postMessage(someData)
```